# Cron Job or any ways to make server perform a git-pull everyday

Tags: linux, github, cron, virtual-machine, cron-task

So I am developing a code and running it in VM server. My main code is , suppose, in this repository. https://github.com/usernae/reponame1. I have cloned this in my VM (git clone https://github.com/usernae/reponame1.git) and doing this.

Now, I will be making changes to this repo, adding codes, files etc.  I need to assure that in every hour or every day the git-pull command is automatically performed here. So I don't need to manually come back in my VM and do it every time I update something. Basically keep github rep files and VM files in sync.

How do I do this? Cron job? Any other? As I am runnng short of time, I would really appreciate complete command/script with proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Cron job is one way to do it, cron comes with built-in helpers [@hourly, @daily](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux)

```
crontab -e
```

Type in your corn expression and save.

```
@hourly cd /path/to/your/project ; git pull
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I am getting a command not found error.

Comment: did you edit your crontab file and add your corn command? what does the log say? not sure what Linux distribution you're using, but do yu see anything on here  ```grep CRON /var/log/syslog```